ESP01 AT Command module with Google Firebase Realtime Database
I am working with a ESP01 module with AT Firmware, I have been trying to establish a communication between ESP01 and the Firebase database to read and write some numerical value but right now I am only able to start a TCP communication using AT+CIPSTART on port 443. But not able to send or read any data from the database it self i am using get and post commands for Sending HTTPS request,but its not working.
This is my AT cmd version that I flashed in my esp01:-
AT version:2.2.0.0(b097cdf 
- ESP8266 
- Jun 17 2021 12:57:45)     14:52:51.223 
-> SDK version:v3.4-22-g967752e2     
14:52:51.223 
-> compile time(6800286):Aug  4 2021 17:20:05     14:52:51.223 
-> Bin version:2.2.0(Cytron_ESP-01S)

Can someone help me with this on how can I successfully communicate with Firebase Database with esp01?
This is my HTTPS request:-
    GET /FRND/R?R=0     Host: frnd-cnnet-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com:443      Connection: close
But every time I am making this HTTPS request I get this following error.:-
<html>
    <head>
        <title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>400 Bad Request</h1>
    </center>
    <center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
    <hr>
    <center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>


Cross site duplicate: Making HTTPS requests using ESP8266 AT commands
